# How to stop auto acknowledgement in MDB (JBOSS , Tibco EMS, Genericra.rar)

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss, tibco-ems

getting warnings like this and I am not able to stop auto ack.

```
768 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] JBAS014105: ActivationConfigProperty acknowledgeMode will be ignored since it is not allowed by resource adapter: genericra
2016-08-10 15:51:38,769 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] JBAS014142: Started message driven bean 'UldLaneMDB' with 'genericra' resource adapter
2016-08-10 15:51:38,770 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] JBAS014105: ActivationConfigProperty acknowledgeMode will be ignored since it is not allowed by resource adapter: genericra
2016-08-10 15:51:38,771 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] JBAS014142: Started message driven bean 'ServiceRecoveryMDB' with 'genericra' resource adapter
2016-08-10 15:51:38,772 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] JBAS014105: ActivationConfigProperty acknowledgeMode will be ignored since it is not allowed by resource adapter: genericra
2016-08-10 15:51:38,772 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] JBAS014105: ActivationConfigProperty acknowledgeMode will be ignored since it is not allowed by resource adapter: genericra
2016-08-10 15:51:38,774 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] JBAS014105: ActivationConfigProperty acknowledgeMode will be ignored since it is not allowed by resource adapter: genericra
2016-08-10 15:51:38,774 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] JBAS014142: Started message driven bean 'PublishAwbMDB' with 'genericra' resource adapter
2016-08-10 15:51:38,774 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] JBAS014142: Started message driven bean 'PublishBookingMDB' with 'genericra' resource adapter
2016-08-10 15:51:38,775 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] JBAS014142: Started message driven bean 'NextWABMDB' with 'genericra' resource adapter
```

Note : i don't have the source of genericra.rar, but it is deployed in all environments, I am not sure what is in there.
I am also new to Java Programming.

This is the ejb-jar.xml

```
<ejb-jar xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    metadata-complete="true">
    <enterprise-beans>
        <message-driven>
            <ejb-name>PublishAwbMDB</ejb-name>
            <ejb-class>com.lsyas.receivebookingservice.mdb.PublishAwbMDB
            </ejb-class>
            <messaging-type>javax.jms.MessageListener</messaging-type>
            <transaction-type>Bean</transaction-type>
            <activation-config>
                <activation-config-property>
                    <activation-config-property-name>destinationType
                    </activation-config-property-name>
                    <activation-config-property-value>javax.jms.Queue
                    </activation-config-property-value>
                </activation-config-property>
                <activation-config-property>
                    <activation-config-property-name>destinationJndiName
                    </activation-config-property-name>
                    <activation-config-property-value>${jms.queue.publishAwb}
                    </activation-config-property-value>
                </activation-config-property>
                <activation-config-property>
                    <activation-config-property-name>connectionFactoryJndiName
                    </activation-config-property-name>
                    <activation-config-property-value>EAIQueueConnectionFactory
                    </activation-config-property-value>
                </activation-config-property>

                <activation-config-property>
                  <activation-config-property-name>acknowledgeMode</activation-config-property-name>
                  <activation-config-property-value>CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE</activation-config-property-value>
                </activation-config-property>

            </activation-config>
        </message-driven>

        <message-driven>
            <ejb-name>PublishBookingMDB</ejb-name>
            <ejb-class>com.lsyas.receivebookingservice.mdb.PublishBookingMDB
            </ejb-class>
            <messaging-type>javax.jms.MessageListener</messaging-type>
            <transaction-type>Bean</transaction-type>
            <activation-config>
                <activation-config-property>
                    <activation-config-property-name>destinationType
                    </activation-config-property-name>
                    <activation-config-property-value>javax.jms.Queue
                    </activation-config-property-value>
                </activation-config-property>
                <activation-config-property>
                    <activation-config-property-name>destinationJndiName
                    </activation-config-property-name>
                    <activation-config-property-value>${jms.queue.publishBookingDetails}
                    </activation-config-property-value>
                </activation-config-property>
                <activation-config-property>
                    <activation-config-property-name>connectionFactoryJndiName
                    </activation-config-property-name>
                    <activation-config-property-value>EAIQueueConnectionFactory
                    </activation-config-property-value>
                </activation-config-property>

                <activation-config-property>
                  <activation-config-property-name>acknowledgeMode</activation-config-property-name>
                  <activation-config-property-value>CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE</activation-config-property-value>
                </activation-config-property>

            </activation-config>
        </message-driven>

        <message-driven>
            <ejb-name>ServiceRecoveryMDB</ejb-name>
            <ejb-class>com.lsyas.receivebookingservice.mdb.ServiceRecoveryMDB
            </ejb-class>
            <messaging-type>javax.jms.MessageListener</messaging-type>
            <transaction-type>Bean</transaction-type>
            <activation-config>
                <activation-config-property>
                    <activation-config-property-name>destinationType
                    </activation-config-property-name>
                    <activation-config-property-value>javax.jms.Queue
                    </activation-config-property-value>
                </activation-config-property>
                <activation-config-property>
                    <activation-config-property-name>destinationJndiName
                    </activation-config-property-name>
                    <activation-config-property-value>${jms.queue.publishServiceRecoveryCase}
                    </activation-config-property-value>
                </activation-config-property>
                <activation-config-property>
                    <activation-config-property-name>connectionFactoryJndiName
                    </activation-config-property-name>
                    <activation-config-property-value>EAIQueueConnectionFactory
                    </activation-config-property-value>
                </activation-config-property>
                <activation-config-property>
                  <activation-config-property-name>acknowledgeMode</activation-config-property-name>
                  <activation-config-property-value>CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE</activation-config-property-value>
                </activation-config-property>
            </activation-config>
        </message-driven>

        <message-driven>
            <ejb-name>UldLaneMDB</ejb-name>
            <ejb-class>com.lsyas.receivebookingservice.mdb.UldLaneMDB</ejb-class>
            <messaging-type>javax.jms.MessageListener</messaging-type>
            <transaction-type>Bean</transaction-type>
            <activation-config>
                <activation-config-property>
                    <activation-config-property-name>destinationType
                    </activation-config-property-name>
                    <activation-config-property-value>javax.jms.Queue
                    </activation-config-property-value>
                </activation-config-property>
                <activation-config-property>
                    <activation-config-property-name>destinationJndiName
                    </activation-config-property-name>
                    <activation-config-property-value>${jms.queue.publishUldLaneDetails}
                    </activation-config-property-value>
                </activation-config-property>
                <activation-config-property>
                    <activation-config-property-name>connectionFactoryJndiName
                    </activation-config-property-name>
                    <activation-config-property-value>EAIQueueConnectionFactory
                    </activation-config-property-value>
                </activation-config-property>
                <activation-config-property>
                  <activation-config-property-name>acknowledgeMode</activation-config-property-name>
                  <activation-config-property-value>CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE</activation-config-property-value>
                </activation-config-property>
            </activation-config>
        </message-driven>

        <message-driven>
            <ejb-name>NextWABMDB</ejb-name>
            <ejb-class>com.lsyas.receivebookingservice.mdb.NextWABMDB</ejb-class>
            <messaging-type>javax.jms.MessageListener</messaging-type>
            <transaction-type>Bean</transaction-type>
            <activation-config>
                <activation-config-property>
                    <activation-config-property-name>destinationType
                    </activation-config-property-name>
                    <activation-config-property-value>javax.jms.Queue
                    </activation-config-property-value>
                </activation-config-property>
                <activation-config-property>
                    <activation-config-property-name>destinationJndiName
                    </activation-config-property-name>
                    <activation-config-property-value>${jms.queue.publishNextWAB}
                    </activation-config-property-value>
                </activation-config-property>
                <activation-config-property>
                    <activation-config-property-name>connectionFactoryJndiName
                    </activation-config-property-name>
                    <activation-config-property-value>EAIQueueConnectionFactory
                    </activation-config-property-value>
                </activation-config-property>
                <activation-config-property>
                  <activation-config-property-name>acknowledgeMode</activation-config-property-name>
                  <activation-config-property-value>CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE</activation-config-property-value>
                </activation-config-property>               
            </activation-config>
        </message-driven>

        <session>
            <ejb-name>AutomaticSchedulerBean</ejb-name>
            <ejb-class>com.lsyas.receivebookingservice.service.AutomaticSchedulerBean</ejb-class>
            <session-type>Stateless</session-type>
            <timer>
                <schedule>
                    <second>01</second>
                    <minute>*</minute>
                    <hour>*</hour>
                    <month>*</month>
                    <year>*</year>
                </schedule>
                <timeout-method>
                    <method-name>backgroundProcessing</method-name>
                    <method-params>
                        <method-param>javax.ejb.Timer</method-param>
                    </method-params>
                </timeout-method>
                <persistent>false</persistent>
            </timer>
        </session>

    </enterprise-beans>
</ejb-jar>
```

one of my MDB looks like this

```
package com.lsyas.receivebookingservice.mdb;

import javax.ejb.MessageDriven;
import javax.ejb.TransactionAttribute;
import javax.ejb.TransactionAttributeType;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.MessageListener;
import javax.jms.ObjectMessage;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;

import org.jboss.ejb3.annotation.ResourceAdapter;
import org.jboss.logging.Logger;

import com.lsyas.receivebookingservice.StatisticExceptionDetector;
import com.lsyas.receivebookingservice.service.MessageProcessor;

@MessageDriven(mappedName = "UldLaneMDB")  
@TransactionAttribute(value = TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)
@ResourceAdapter("genericra.rar")  
public class UldLaneMDB implements MessageListener {

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(UldLaneMDB.class);

    private final MessageProcessor messageProcessor;

    public UldLaneMDB() {       
        this.messageProcessor = new MessageProcessor();     
        StatisticExceptionDetector statisticExceptionDetector = new StatisticExceptionDetector();       
        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(statisticExceptionDetector);      
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        try {
            if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
                TextMessage msg = (TextMessage) message;
                this.messageProcessor.processUldLaneXMLMessage(msg.getText());
            } else if (message instanceof ObjectMessage) {
                LOG.error("Received message was an ObjectMessage and will be ignored!");    
            } else {
                LOG.error("Received message was not an Object- or TextMessage and will be ignored!");
            }

        } catch (JMSException e) {
            LOG.error("Exception during onMessage.", e);
        }

    }
}
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your use of CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE is incorrect:

```
            <activation-config-property>
              <activation-config-property-name>acknowledgeMode</activation-config-property-name>
              <activation-config-property-value>CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE</activation-config-property-value>
            </activation-config-property>
```

Please see:

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncfu.html#bncfw

```
Note - In the Java EE platform, a CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE session can be used only in an application client, not in a web component or enterprise bean.
```

For a Message Driven Bean, the JEE container is responsible for acknowledging the messages.  JBoss will acknowledge the message once the onMessage() method completes.

Comment: Thank You for the information,,
But i want to send the acknowledgement manually like message.acknowledge()

Comment: Even if i keep DUPS_OK_ACKNOWLEDGE it is saying same.

Comment: The JEE container  is responsible for acknowledging the messages.  This is out of your hands.

Comment: Well, with a container managed transaction, the container must also manage the message acknowledgement.